# Amazon EC2 ssh timeout due inactivity

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am able to issue commands to my EC2 instances via SSH and these commands logs answers which I'm supposed to keep watching for a long time. The bad thing is that SSH command is closed after some time due to my inactivity and I'm no longer able to see what's going on with my instances.

How can I disable/increase timeout in Amazon Linux machines?

The error looks like this:

```
Read from remote host ec2-50-17-48-222.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using `screen` or `byobu` and the problem will likely go away.  What's more, even if the connection is lost, you can reconnect and restore access to the same terminal screen you had before, via `screen -r` or `byobu -r`.

byobu is an enhancement for screen, and has a wonderful set of options, such as an estimate of EC2 costs.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for either of these? Neither appears to come preinstalled on the EC2 hosts, and from what I have read you're supposed to run them on the server.

Comment: I prefer @brandnewcode's `ServerAliveInterval`, below.  I have been using tmux, which is similar to screen.  An unintended benefit of tmux is a clock on the status bar which updates every minute, keeping the connection open.  tl;dr: `tmux` to start a session, and `tmux a` to re-attach.

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer as it answers a different question.

Comment: One of the best solution is what mauriciomdea have given. No need to reconnect. Works like charm.

Comment: To me that is not a solution to ssh losing it's connection. It is a workaround for it. Gnu screen is useful to keep logs available upon disconnect, but it doesn't keep the connection running.

Answer (score 191):

You can set a keep alive option in your `~/.ssh/config` file on the client's home dir:

```
ServerAliveInterval 50
```

Amazon AWS usually drops your connection after only 60 seconds of inactivity, so this option will ping the server every 50 seconds and keep you connected indefinitely.

Note - This is to be set client side only and not server side. We have `ClientAliveInterval` for server side which can be set similarly.

Comment: this setting is on the client side, as opposed to the AWS server, right? Would be worth mentioning in the answer. Also, are you sure about the 60 seconds? It certainly takes far longer than that for my connections to time out.

Comment: Yes, it's on the client side, on your ssh config on your *nix computer. I'll update the answer, thanks!

For me it's actually 120 seconds, but I have a coworker working in another region and it timeouts in 60 seconds for him. Don't ask me why, I don't work at Amazon! That's why I said 'usually' 60 seconds. I thought it prudent to recommend 50 seconds because 1. it will work for almost everyone and 2. it's not going to thrash your network connection, it's just a ping. You could put 10 seconds and it will still be light enough to not fall into some kind of server ban.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was pain to reconnect all the time just after 1 minute of inactivity. It helped me.

Comment: Perfect Answer! To expand, the file should be `chmod 644 .ssh/config` if its not already created by the system.

Comment: This answer explains this further with two more useful settings: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-d

Comment: Does this setting get propagated through an ssh proxy?

Answer (score 79):

Assuming your Amazon EC2 instance is running Linux (and the very likely case that you are using SSH-2, not 1), the following should work pretty handily:

1. Remote into your EC2 instance.

   ```
   ssh -i <YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE>.pem <INTERNET_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE>
   ```
2. Add a "client-alive" directive to the instance's SSH-server configuration file.

   ```
   echo 'ClientAliveInterval 60' | sudo tee --append /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
3. Restart or reload the SSH server, for it to recognize the configuration change.

   - The command for that on **Ubuntu Linux** would be..

     ```
     sudo service ssh restart
     ```
   - On **any other Linux**, though, the following is probably correct..

     ```
     sudo service sshd restart
     ```
4. Disconnect.

   ```
   logout
   ```

The next time you SSH into that EC2 instance, those super-annoying frequent connection freezes/timeouts/drops should hopefully be gone.

This is also helps with Google Compute Engine instances, which come with similarly annoying default settings.

***Warning:*** Do note that **TCPKeepAlive** settings (which also exist) are subtly, yet distinctly different from the **ClientAlive** settings that I propose above, and that changing TCPKeepAlive settings from the default may actually hurt your situation rather than help.

More info here: http://man.openbsd.org/?query=sshd_config

Comment: Or just: echo 'ClientAliveInterval 60' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Or uncomment #ClientAliveInterval

Comment: @DimiDak Have you actually tried the command that you suggest? Probably like yourself, I always just use nano to do such edits; but the normative recipe-styled format of answers on Stack Overflow called for instructions that are copy-pasteable, and thus I made the same mistake as you did in the untested, original copy-pasteable [ie., not using an interactive text editor app] version of my instructions. The old comments to this answer that seem to have vanished (??) explained this; and the revision history of this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24360827/revisions] does also, somewhat.

Comment: What's wrong with --> echo 'ClientAliveInterval 60' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config   ?

Comment: On centos7 AMI the command to restart `sshd` is `systemctl reload sshd`

Comment: works still ! :)

Answer (score 9):

I know for Putty you can utilize a keepalive setting so it will send some activity packet every so often as to not go "idle" or "stale"

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#S4.13.4

If you are using other client let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mobaxterm, free tabbed SSH terminal with below settings-

```
Settings -> Configuration -> SSH -> SSH keepalive
```

remember to restart Mobaxterm app after changing the setting.

Comment: Most perfect and acceptable answer and not sure why no one voted this answer.
Thanks @Panky it is solving my problem with extreme easy way as you suggested.

Comment: Team follow this approach only, no need to do any changes on EC2 instances.

Comment: This suggestion did not work for me. My MobaXterm is version 21.3 build 4736 and I am connecting to AWS EC2 but after around 2 minutes it disconnects even though the keepalive checbox was selected and MobaXterm was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the SSH connection timeout in Linux (for example RedHat), you can adjust the configuration settings in the SSH server configuration file (sshd_config). Here's how you can do it:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Look for the ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax items. If there is not specify you can add them at the end of the file.

```
ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 6
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

[image]

When you save configuration you must restart ssh or sshd service (it depends type of Linux)

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

OR

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

**ClientAliveInterval**: Specifies the interval (in seconds) that the server will wait before sending a null packet to the client to check if the connection is still alive.

**ClientAliveCountMax**: Specifies the number of times the server will send a keepalive message without receiving a response from the client before disconnecting.

**TCPKeepAlive**: It sends an empty TCP ACK packet

If You use Putty please check if this connection options is checked
[image]

Answer (score -13):

I have a 10+ custom AMIs all based on Amazon Linux AMIs and I've never run into any timeout issues due to inactivity on a SSH connection.  I've had connections stay open more than 24 hrs, without running a single command.  I don't think there are any timeouts built into the Amazon Linux AMIs.

Comment: I think it's sufficient to say that more people are getting timed out than not and one possible reason why you're not getting timed-out is because you have a client setting for your ssh which pings the remote peer occasionally to keep the disconnect/reset from occurring on your connections.